# Add custom keyboard shortcut to change keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

In windows, I usually use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to change between keyboard layout. How can I achieve this in Ubuntu? I mean, what command I have to use keyboard shortcuts settings?

Comment: by default: Super + Space

Answer (score 0):

You can set the shortcut in your **System Settings** panel at **Text Entry** by entering your new accelerator keys (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) in the text field(s) *"Switch to next/previous source using:"*

Does that work for you or do you insist in a terminal command?

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)